# Problems finding interval of convergence about $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

I used the ratio to find the convergence range.
I find that it converges at $-1 <x <1$.
**I thought about it to see if it contained -1 and 1**, but I ran into a problem. If $x = 1$, I couldn't find a way to calculate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$. It seems that convergence will occur, but it was difficult to grasp the process.
Which part am I not aware of?

Comment: It converges everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Radfius of convergence is $R=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{
n!}}{\frac{1}{(n+1)!}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)=\infty$, so it converges everywhere, not just for $x\in [-1,1]$. Also, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}=e$ since $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio test shouldn't give you the radius of convergence that you claimed. Call $a_n=\frac{x^n}{n!}.$ Then, we know that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<1$$ will guarantee us absolute convergence. Compute that

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\left|\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{x^n}\right|=\left|\frac{x}{n+1}\right|.$$ For any $x\in\mathbb{R},$ this limit is zero, which is less than $1$. Hence, it converges absolutely for every real $x$, meaning that the radius of convergence is $\infty.$